# Listen for new audio objects in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, events, volume

Is there an event that can be hooked on to, when a new audio object is added/removed?

I want a list similar to the Windows Volume Mixer - all the current volume objects.

I'm currently checking for new processes, then checking if they have a volume object, but the volume objects are often created *after* the process, not with it, so this is not a very viable solution.

Does such an event exist, that can be listened to in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when a new virtual drive is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912969/detect-when-a-new-virtual-drive-is-created)

Comment: @JuanR Is a virtual drive what I am looking for here? I might not know the right terms, and connect them with volume objects, but I don't see how that question, or its answers relates to my question? Please elaborate :)

Comment: Take a moment to read the answer in that link. You will see he has a method to subscribe to volume changes.

Comment: @JuanR Can you provide an example, on how my question is linked to the answer from the question you linked? I have looked through it, and don't see any listeners being subscribed to. I may not have the required knowledge in C# (or this particular field) to see the solution myself here. I have tried running the code from the answer, but nothing happens when a new application with a volume object is opened. I don't see the resemblance with TrueCrypt and virtual drives to my problem here.